# Facing error in running the programming

Tags: c++11

I am trying to run this program, taking vertices of a triangle as inputs.
But i am facing errors. Can someone help me with this ?

What I am trying to do create a point class, inherit in a triangle class and accept the vertices of triangle as inputs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#Defines a class Point.
class Point
{
    private:
        float x;
        float y;
    public:
        int read_Point(Point &P)
        {   
            std::cin >> P.x >> P.y;
        }
};

#Defines a class Triangle
class Triangle : public Point
{
    private:
        std::vector<Point> P;
    public:
        int make_triangle()
        {
            P=std::vector<Point>(3);
            read_Traingle();
            return 0;
        }
        void read_Traingle()
        {
            read_Point(P[1]);
            read_Point(P[2]);
            read_Point(P[3]);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Triangle Tri;
    Tri.make_triangle();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not even going to tell us what the errors are?

Comment: I am getting this error "Aborted (core dumped)". I am able pass all the vertices as input, but then it reports this error and crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialized the vector with 3 `P=std::vector<Point>(3);` then you tried to read the element P[3] `read_Point(P[3]);`

increase the size of vector or read the vector starting with index zero.